# Closed Connection:next Error in resultSet

Tags: java, jdbc

The connection doesn't seem to be closed, I'm thinking perhaps it's due to callableStatement being nested inside preparedStatement. The query works and shows the first row that I'm looking for, but the connection closes after the first iteration of the loop.

Here's the code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Connection connection = ConnectionUtil_Basic.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(generateQuery());
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
        
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            int mbr = resultSet.getInt(1);              
            String ime = resultSet.getString(2);
            String prezime = resultSet.getString(3);
            int brRadnika = ExecuteFun.getRadnici(mbr);
            
            System.out.printf("%-4d %-8s %-8s %-4d\n", mbr, ime, prezime, brRadnika);
        }
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here's the method from ExecuteFun that uses callableStatement:

(F_SEL_BrRadnikaSefova is a function in SQL connected to my database)

```java
public static int getRadnici(int mbr_sefa) {
    try (Connection connection = ConnectionUtil_Basic.getConnection();
            CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{? = call F_SEL_BrRadnikaSefova(?) }")) {
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
        callableStatement.setLong(2, mbr_sefa);

        callableStatement.execute();

        int result = (Integer) callableStatement.getObject(1);
        return result;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return NULL;
    }
```

And here's the stacktrace:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection: next
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:247)
    at upit2.Upit2_Sefovi.main(Upit2_Sefovi.java:20)
```

Comment: I'm guessing that you decided to cache the connection in `ConnectionUtil_Basic.getConnection()`. Don't. If you use the same `Connection` object it will close any open cursors (e.g. `ResultSet`) you have.

Comment: `try (Connection connection = ConnectionUtil_Basic.getConnection();` - the connection will be closed after this `try` block  exits

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Likely you're storing and reusing the connection in `ConnectionUtil_Basic.getConnection()`.